# Attribute in background-image and background url

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to apply a filter to my background image however I am having issues with CSS attributes URL and linear gradient. I would like to have the background image of the

```css
.bg-image-full {
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

.background-tint {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(62, 63, 64, 0.6), rgba(62, 63, 64, 0.6));
 }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <header class="py-5 bg-image-full background-tint" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.japantimes.2xx.jp/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/n-tokyo-a-20180715.jpg');">
  <img alt="ava" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto rounded-circle" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Favicon_250x250.png">
 </header>
```

city with a background tint on top but it won't work properly. Since the background image is on top off the tint. I would also like to keep the image URL source in the HTML code and not css because I am using the class for multiple images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an absolutely positioned pseudo-element to do that:

```css
.bg-image-full {
  background: no-repeat 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.background-tint,
.background-tint .img-fluid {
  position: relative;
}

.background-tint:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '\a0';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(62, 63, 64, 0.6), rgba(62, 63, 64, 0.6));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="py-5 bg-image-full background-tint" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.japantimes.2xx.jp/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/n-tokyo-a-20180715.jpg');">
  <img alt="ava" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto rounded-circle" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Favicon_250x250.png">
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

first, of all, it will not show at all, not because it is under the background-image, but because you are overriding the gradient, when you set the background-image inline, on the element.

For your specific use case, you can simply use a pseudo-element to hold the gradient.
This will place the gradient on top of your element/background-image:

```
.background-tint::after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0;
   width: 100%; height: 100%;
   background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(62, 63, 64, 0.6), rgba(62, 63, 64, 0.6));
}
```

If this overlays undesirably, you can add a z-index to your inner `img`:

```
header > img { position: relative; z-index: 2 }
```